# How to change the position of a vertex of a given threejs.Box3?

Tags: javascript, three.js

My aim here is to create a box, then change one of its vertex's position through geometry, and then display it.

```
var anchor = new THREE.Vector3( 300, 300, 3 );
var cursor = new THREE.Vector3( 500, 550, 50 );

var box2       = new THREE.Box3( anchor, cursor );
var box2Helper = new THREE.Box3Helper( box2 );

box2Helper.geometry.vetices[0] = new THREE.Vector3( 20, 20, 20 );
box2Helper.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

scene.add( box2Helper );
```

This code works fine without those two geometry lines.
What is the way to change the position of the existing vertexes of the box through geometry class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion here about what the Box3 class is... It's just a 3d boundingbox.. To make a deformable box with vertices, you want a new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial() )

then you can modify the mesh.geometry.vertices like you are doing..

THREE.Box3 is more of a utility class used to represent bounding boxes of things.. it's used for frustum culling and stuff.